# envsubst to replace a variable in javascript file with an environment variable

Tags: javascript, environment-variables

I have a variable in javascript such as var a = $MyEnv
I want to replace this with the env variable $MYENV on the host os. How can I achieve this using envsubt?

I tried doing teh following

```
export TEST="someapi"
created a text file that contains $TEST called test.txt
envsubst > test.txt
```

this command outputs the value of the environmental variable but does not replace it in the file

Comment: Based on reading the manual for it… You just run envsubst on the script. That's what it does. It's a very simple program. What's the problem?

Comment: so is envsubst $MYENV javascript.js the syntax?

Comment: does the javascript file need to have  variable with teh same name?

Comment: people downvoting it, reason it or answer it

Comment: Are you executing the file on that host (e.g using node)?

Comment: yes I am, does envsubst also replace the variable in javascript?

Comment: People are downvoting this because you are asking them to repeat [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) which only has 165 words in the relevant section!

Comment: It works on standard input. Which is text. JavaScript source code is text. So yes, of course it works on JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't overridden STDIN, you are going to be trying to read from what the user types.

Since you have redirected STDOUT to the text file, you are going to overwrite it with the output of envsubst.

You need to make the file containing your data STDIN and write to a new file.

```
envsubst < test.txt > newtest.txt
```